# Usage of "Trainers having experienced working with XYZ organisation"

Tags: word-usage, writing

I am preparing a creative brochure for a workshop, where I need to mention our trainer's experience as "Our trainers have experience working with XYZ(elite organisation)".
Could any one help me to get a better way of writing the same in a more creative and attractive way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange EL&U! I think you need to give us a bit more information about the kinds of things your trainers are involved in. (By the way, I assume you have more than one trainer, in which case the possessive of trainer is TRAINERS' (as in "our trainers' experience"). With this information you can expand your sentence or even use it as a thesis sentence for an entire paragraph. Being more specific about the areas in which your trainers [plural noun, not possessive] have expertise is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If XYZ were a tool, you might use working with but as it is an organization I would suggest *"Our trainers have worked for (or as a part of) XYZ (or have been working if they still are)"*